# How can I mount a homemade image file as a partition in Windows?

Tags: windows

I grabbed every sector off of a remote flash device and concatenated them all into a file.  Now I want to recreate the file system on my machine.  It seems like this is something one of you has done before.  Any help?

The partition in the image uses FAT16.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Daemon Tools Lite.](http://www.filehippo.com/download_daemon_tools/)

Comment: DT says that the image is corrupted. I think this might be because the file I'm feeding it has the boot sector at the beginning and the partition I want is offset 32 sectors.  Do you know how I can slice off the first 16K of this file?
EDIT: OK. Searching for split rather than slice works a lot better. Nevermind the last question.

Comment: The command I'm using to split the file:
dd bs=1 skip=16K if=infile of=outfile

Comment: Actually this is a lot faster: dd bs=16K skip=1 if=infile of=outfile

Comment: Removing the first 16K moved the begining of the partition to the beginning of the file, but Windows still can't read the mounted file system.

Comment: @jjfine: daemon tools is good for ISO and UDF images, but i don't know if it'll handle other filesystem images.

Answer (score 0):

filedisk might work http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/